# Count rows minus 1

Tags: php

Im making a counter that will count the data on attendance table 
on database and display it on my homepage, I manage to work it 
by counting the number of rows on the datatable, Now im having 
trouble of how i can subtract the number of rows -1 if a student 
fill-in the time-out column. For example a student fill-in the time-in
it will diplay to 1 on the counter and if that student fill-in time-out it will minus to 
1 and in the counter it will display 0. I hope you can help me or give me a better approach
to achieve this.  Advance thanks.

here is what ive done so far.

```
<div class="card" style=" margin-left:-207px;left:350px;; bottom:220px;">
                    <div class="row mt-4 mb-3">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-3 text-left pl-4">
                          <a class="p-2 m-2 fa-lg fb-ic"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x blue-text"> </i></a>
                           </div>
                         <div class="col-md-9 col-9 text-right pr-5">
                           <p class="font-small grey-text mb-1">Students</p>
                           <h5 class="ml-4 mb-2 font-weight-bold">
                           <?php include_once('connection.php');
                           $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT timeout, timein, count(timein) As total FROM student_att ") ;
                           $values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
                           $num_rows=$values["total"];
                           echo $num_rows;
                           ?></h5>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do the same count for timeout then subtract them,

```
<?php include_once('connection.php');
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT timeout, timein, count(timein) As total,count(timeout) as totalTimeout FROM student_att ") ;
  $values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
  $num_rows=$values["total"];
  $num_timeout = $values["totalTimeout "];
  echo ($num_rows-$num_timeout);
 ?>
```

Comment: @ Ray A , i got an error it says undefine totalTimeout